# Highcharts Bar Extend past MaxValue

Tags: highcharts, max

I want to make a simple bar chart in Highcharts. However, I would like the max value to be less than the actual maximum value in the series, and provide a visual clue that that is happening.

If you referenced the highcharts demo:
http://www.highcharts.com/demo/bar-basic

I want the scale to end at 4,000, even though the longest bar extends to 4054. That part is easy, by just setting the Max.

But, I want some visual indicator to let the user know that the bar extends beyond the max. This is for cases where the highest value in the series is so high, it makes it hard to see the other values in the graph relative to each other. We essentially don't need to be concerned by the outlier, but need to know it lies outside the axis.

Thinking it through, I can set the ticks to be less than the max value, and end on tickInterval false. Is there another option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well but where this information should be displayed?

I've prepared simple example which marked this information in tooltip and in report div below chart.

http://jsfiddle.net/sbochan/8sKcs/

```
$(function () {
var chart;
$(document).ready(function() {
    chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'bar'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Historic World Population by Region'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: 'Source: Wikipedia.org'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Africa', 'America', 'Asia', 'Europe', 'Oceania'],
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max:4000,
            title: {
                text: 'Population (millions)',
                align: 'high'
            },
            labels: {
                overflow: 'justify'
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            formatter: function() {
                if(this.y > (this.series.chart.yAxis[0].max))
                    return this.series.name +': '+ this.y + ' max is smaller: '+this.series.chart.yAxis[0].max ;
                else
                    return this.series.name +': '+ this.y;
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true
                }
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            name: 'Year 2008',
            data: [973, 914, 4054, 732, 34]
        }]
    },function(chart){

        var max = chart.yAxis[0].max,
            content = '<h2>Points</h2><br/>';

        $.each(chart.series,function(i,serie){
            $.each(serie.data,function(j,data){
               if(data.y > max)
                   content += 'Point: '+data.y+' is bigger than max: '+max;
            });
        });

        $('#report').html(content);

    });
});
```

});

EDIT:

You can add also

```
data.graphic.attr({
                   fill:'yellow'
                 });
```

To change color of bar.

Comment: Think you for this. What I was hoping to do, is maybe make the bar a different color like silver.  I tried adding that behavior to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/manishap/WQkeQ/2/ . This code doesn't work for two reasons: 1) it turned all bars silver. 2) After viewing the tooltip it defaults back to blue not retaining the explicit color setting. Do you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Sebastian,Thanks for the response. I've utilized your suggestions. I have a new issue. The color change I've assigned to the bar doesn't persist if a user views the tooltip. On rollover/rollout the bar that was a different color reverts to the default. What option do I need to affect to change this. I've updated the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/WQkeQ/4/